# Retrieving attributes from a CDK stack or app construct tree for offline tests

Tags: python, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

In order to ease adoption of the CDK toolkit in my company's cloud department, I'd like to write some diagnostics tools to test the architecture described in a CDK app before deploying it. Specifically whether the Security Group rules and IAM policies allow for communication between instances on the correct ports.

However I can't seem to access security group rules created between instances in the stack. Is there any way to do so that doesn't involve wrapping the SecurityGroup construct or Connections class to store all rules as you add them(because that means no backwards compatibility among other concerns)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see what you have already tried ? A code snippet maybe.

Answer (score 0):

CDK just does not seem to expose very many attributes. I can't piece together the topology in any practical way for now.